Relativized extensionality $\implies$ existence of a transitive set isomorphic to the first one
Background. Given two sets $A$ and $B$, we say that $A$ is isomorphic to $B$ if there exists a bijection $f : A \to B$ such that $\forall x,y \in A \; y \in x \leftrightarrow f(y) \in f(x)$. We work in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and cannot make use of $\epsilon$-recursion principle.
Problem. Prove that if a set $S$ satisfies the axiom of extensionality relativized, i.e. $\forall x,y \in S \ \forall z \in S (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x = y$, there exists a transitive set isomorphic to $S$.
My approach. The first remark to do is that, by the axiom of foundation, there exists $s \in S$ such that $s \cap S = \emptyset$ and, since relativized extensionality holds in $S$, $s$ is unique. Knowing that in a transitive set $\emptyset$ is the only $\epsilon$-minimal element, I think strongly hints the fact that it has to be $f(s) = \emptyset$. Furthermore one may think to construct $S' = \{y | y \cup \{s\} = x \in S\}$ (it's an abuse of notation but only to show briefly the idea), and with the same argument find another unique $\epsilon$-minimal element $s'$ for $S'$,
such that $s \in s'$, but I don't if this way to procede leads to something. I think the axiom scheme of replacement is the only way to have the set we're looking for, so, in order to apply it, I need a class function (i.e. a formula that respects the fundamental propriety of a function - $\forall x \in S \ \exists ! y \in T$ etc.), and the argument above should (?) lead me to define such function. Any hint?
Edit 1. I think this could be the intended way to construct the set. Let's define by transfinite recursion:
$$f_{\alpha} := \begin{cases}f_0 = \emptyset \\\\ f_{\alpha+1} = f_\alpha \cup \{(x,f_\alpha[x])\}_{x \in V_{\alpha + 1}\setminus V_\alpha}
\\\\ f_\lambda = \bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda} f_\gamma \end{cases}$$
let $\sigma := \operatorname{rank}(S)$, i.e. $S \in V_{\sigma + 1}$, we define the followings:
$$T := \bigcup_{\alpha \in \sigma} f_{\alpha}[S \cap V_{\alpha}] \qquad f := \bigcup_{\alpha \in \sigma} f_\alpha$$
(I took the union over $\sigma$ since from that point on the sequences are constant, so I don't need to go further, in order to get the set and the map) we want to prove that $T$ is a transitive set and $f : S \to T$ is an isomorphism. In order to do so we temporarily assume that:

$\forall \alpha \in \operatorname{Ord} \ f_\alpha[S \cap V_{\alpha}]$ is a transitive set.
$\forall \alpha \in \operatorname{Ord} \ f_{\alpha} : S \cap V_{\alpha} \to f_\alpha[S \cap V_{\alpha}]$ is an isomorphism.
$\forall \alpha < \beta \ f_{\alpha} \subseteq f_{\beta}$

Once we have these proprieties it's easy to check that:

$T$ is a transitive set, in fact, if $y \in x \in T$, by definition we have $y \in x \in f_{\beta}[S \cap V_{\beta}]$, for some $\beta \in \sigma$, and so via 1 we get $y \in f_{\beta}[S \cap V_{\beta}] \implies y \in T$.
$f : S \to T$ is an isomorphism, the surjectivity is trivial by definition and the injectivity is due to the fact that $f$ is union of injective maps, so we only need to prove that given $y \in x \in S$, let $\delta := \operatorname{rank}(x)$, we have:

$$y \in x \overset{\text{via 2}}{\iff} f_{\delta + 1}(y) \in f_{\delta + 1}(x) \overset{\text{definition of $f$}}{\iff} f(y) \in f(x)$$
So the last thing to do is to prove 1,2,3.

If $y \in x \in f_{\alpha}[S \cap V_{\alpha}]$, let's assume that $x = f_\alpha(z) = f_{\operatorname{rank}(z)}[z]$, so $y = f_{\operatorname{rank}(z)}(y') = f_{\alpha}(y')$, thus $y \in f_{\alpha}[S \cap V_{\alpha}]$ (technically we are assuming 3, so this should be proven after 3).
Given $f_\alpha$ we want to prove that is injective and $\forall x,y \in S \cap V_{\alpha} \ f_\alpha(y) \in f_{\alpha}(x) \iff y \in x$ (the surjectivity is trivial by definition). We can use the transfinite induction, the case $\alpha = 0$ is trivial, for the successor case we have:

$$\begin{align} f_{\alpha + 1}(x) = f_{\alpha + 1}(y) &\iff f_{\alpha + 1}[x] = f_{\alpha + 1}[y] &&(\star) \\\\ &\iff f_{\alpha}[x] = f_{\alpha}[y] &&(x,y \subseteq V_\alpha) \\\\ &\iff \{z \in y | z \in S \cap V_{\alpha}\} =  \{z \in x | z \in S \cap V_{\alpha}\} &&(\text{inductive hp.}) \\\\ &\iff x = y &&(\text{relativized exten.})\end{align}$$
where $(\star)$ holds due to the fact that, given $x \in S \cap V_{\alpha}$, let $\rho := \operatorname{rank}(x)$, we have:
$$f_\alpha(x) = f_{\rho + 1}(x) = f_\rho[x] = f_\alpha [x]$$
For the isomorphism propriety in the successor case we've:
$$\begin{align} 
f_{\alpha + 1}(y) \in f_{\alpha + 1}(x) &\iff f_{\alpha + 1}(y) \in f_{\alpha + 1}[x] &&(\star)\\\\ 
&\iff f_{\alpha + 1}(y) = f_{\alpha + 1}(z) &&(z \in x) \\\\
&\iff y = z \in x &&(\text{injectivity of $f_{\alpha + 1}$}) \\\\
&\iff y \in x
\end{align}$$
The limit case should be trivial for both injectivity and the isomorphism propriety.

Via transfinite induction. The case $\alpha = 0$ is trivial, we assume for the successor case that $\forall \beta < \alpha \ f_\beta \subseteq f_\alpha$, and prove that $\forall \beta < \alpha + 1 \ f_\beta \subseteq f_{\alpha + 1}$. Because $\beta < \alpha + 1 \iff \beta \leq \alpha$,
if $\beta < \alpha$ the thesis is true by inductive hypothesis, if $\beta = \alpha$, by the definition above $f_{\alpha} \subseteq f_{\alpha + 1}$. The limit case should be trivial since $\forall \gamma < \lambda \ f_\gamma \subseteq f_{\lambda}$ due to the definition itself.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
